# How to search through dropdown list and web content at the same time using Ctrl+f?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser

I want to search through web content on my web page as well as from the dropdown present in the web page. Is there any way to do it using JavaScript or jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Press F12 -> Ctrl+F --> Search the text

[image]

Comment: I do not want any user to use developer option on my webpage

Comment: @Vidit Have you found any solution for this?

Comment: @IT_Philic nope still looking for it.

Comment: nope i just changed the functionality and sticked to specific keywords